# Batch File - Loop through wildcard search, extract contents

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file, Sample.Job.txt, this is the contents:

```
Load.SQL.Sample.Basic.Data
Script.Calc.Sample.Basic.AggAll
```

Here's my batch file:

```
FOR /F %%i in (Sample.Job.txt) DO (
echo %%i>>Test.txt
)
```

The contents of Sample.Job.bat are written to Test.txt correctly.

But if I change it to include a wildcard search for the files:

```
FOR %%i in (*.Job.txt) DO (
echo %%i>>Test.txt
)
```

It just prints the name of the file, Sample.Job.txt, to Test.txt. How do I incorporate a wildcard search?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just nested a loop to do what I wanted to do:

```
FOR %%i in (*.Job.txt) DO (
FOR /F %%a in (%%i) DO (
    echo %%a>>Test.txt
)
)
```